# How to align a JLabel to the bottom of a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I would like the `JLabel` item3 to be located at the bottom of the `JPanel`, since sometimes it appears on top of the 2d array I have in the window.   I tried to use the         `item3.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.BOTTOM)`. method but it did not work. Any suggestions?

```
public class Sokoban extends JPanel {

private Contents[][] field;
private Rectangle2D.Double r1;
private static final Color[] colours = {
        Color.BLACK, Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.CYAN, Color.MAGENTA, Color.BLUE, Color.YELLOW
    };

private LevelReader lr = new LevelReader();
private int currentLevel;
private Contents [][] levelData;
private int countMoves = 1;
JLabel item3 = new JLabel("ccc");


long time1;


public Sokoban(){
    lr.readLevels("m1.txt");

    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(900,500));
    this.setFocusable(true);
    this.requestFocus();
    this.addKeyListener(new MyKeyListener());
    initLevel(0);
    this.add(item3);
    item3.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.BOTTOM);





}

public static void main (String[] args) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Sokoban");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    f.add(new Sokoban());


    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);  


}
```

Comment: It really depends on what you want. Check this out to see the different types of LayoutManagers available and examples of them: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Comment: The other answers have told you what you can do, so I'll just explain why your current solution doesn't work. You are misunderstanding what `setVerticalAlignment(int)` does. It sets where the text appears relative to the label, not where the label appears in its container.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use `BorderLayout` and add the label to the `PAGE_END` position of the container

```
setLayout(new BorderLayout());
add(itemLabel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
```

Of course you'll need to set the horizontal alignment to achieve the alignment along the X-axis as produced originally by the label's `JPanel` `FlowLayout` container

```
JLabel itemLabel = new JLabel("ccc", JLabel.CENTER);
```